# Make It Look Like You Are Typing A Text In A Command Prompt

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, marquee

I am looking for a way to show a random nvarchar field from a SQL Server 2008 database in my Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET web project.

but there is one condition:

I want the text to look like you are typing it in a command prompt.

Is marquee my solution?

Can you show me an example of binding from database & command prompt typing?

Comment: What do you mean by "seem"? I think something is lost in translation ;-)

Comment: i think the text should appear on the page letter by letter as if someone was typing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [jTypewriter (a jQuery plugin)](http://www.dummwiam.com/jTypeWriter), I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: the example #1 (upper Link) is exactly that i want (with command prompt sign)
but how can i read data from db with jquery?
(i am new in jquery)

Comment: Two ways: Firstly read the data in your server-side code and inject it into the page as it's sent to the client. Secondly, create an AJAX end point in your server-side code that returns your random string, then use JQuery to periodically call the AJAX end point and then inject the returned string into your jTypewriter elements.

Comment: can u tell me how can i use jTypewriter (a jQuery plugin) to getting a SINGLE Line Just Like Marquee in Horizontal mode?

Comment: @LostLord Are you looking for the text to be constrained within a single line and for the beginning of the text to scroll off the left hand side of the area?

Comment: I think you'll need to approach the developer behind jTypewriter to see if that's possible. I don't believe it is by default. The difficulty is not knowing how wide the text will be and whether characters need to be removed from the head of the displayed string.